# How to place buttons in a canvas dynamically so that it won't overlap each other?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, canvas, windows-phone-8.1

I am writing an application in C#, WPF, Windows Phone 8.1 apps and I have one canvas in a 480x480 rectangular grid, and I want to put some buttons onto the canvas based on certain logic, there will be minimum 5 buttons and maximum 12-15 buttons, now based upon certain conditions I want to put buttons in the canvas so that it does not overlap with each other.

I started with Grid idea initially with number of rows and columns set and every row/column will have only one buttons,  Suppose I have 6 buttons I will call this method `CreateButtonsControls(3,3);`  but the way it placed the Buttons inside the grid it looks very monotonous to me.

```
private void CreateButtonsControls(int rows, int columns)
    {
        // Create a Grid
        Grid rootGrid = new Grid();

        // It will create columns
        createColumns(rootGrid, columns);

        // It will create rows
        createRow(rootGrid, rows);

        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
            {
                Button button = new Button();
                button.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right;
                button.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
                button.Margin = new Thickness(3);
                button.Width = 50;
                button.Height = 50;
                button.Content = "12";
                Grid.SetRow(button, i);
                Grid.SetColumn(button, j);
                rootGrid.Children.Add(button);
            }
        }
        // This will add the root grid to UI
        grdButton.Children.Add(rootGrid);

    }
```

and I thought to implement it in a canvas. I want that all the buttons will be placed inside the canvas scatter way. But I don't know how can I achieve this.

There is one property
`Canvas.SetLeft(UIControl, positionX )
 Canvas.SetTop(UIControl, positionY )`

But How do I decide this positionX and positionY at runtime so that it doesnot overlap eachother, any idea or suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Why would you, when having six buttons, call it with 3 columns and 3 rows? That seems like it would be for 9 buttons...

Comment: Its just an example I given, but I want to place buttons dynamically in an abstract way, and I think that Canvas is a better options, any ideas!

Comment: You have failed to define how you want them placed. You say `dynamically in an abstract way` but that has an extremely large gap for interpretation. Perhaps you should include a couple examples of how you wish the end result to display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this, first of all, assuming a canvas called MyCanvas in your markup:

```
<Canvas Name="MyCanvas" Loaded="MyCanvas_Loaded">        
</Canvas>
```

Then a helper class that will allow us to check whether a button will overlap with another:

```
class ButtonPosition {
    public int TopLeftX { get; set; }
    public int TopLeftY { get; set; }
    public int BottomRightX {
        get { return TopLeftX + Width; }
    }
    public int BottomRightY {
        get { return TopLeftY + Height; }
    }
    public int Width { get; set; }
    public int Height { get; set; }

    public ButtonPosition(int topLeftX, int topLeftY, int width, int height) {
        TopLeftX = topLeftX;
        TopLeftY = topLeftY;
        Width = width;
        Height = height;
    }

    public bool Overlaps(ButtonPosition bp) {
        return (bp.TopLeftX < this.BottomRightX && bp.BottomRightX > this.TopLeftX && bp.TopLeftY < this.BottomRightY && bp.BottomRightY > this.TopLeftY);
    }
}
```

Then, when the canvas has loaded:

```
private void MyCanvas_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    int numButtons = 20;
    int buttonWidth = 50;
    int buttonHeight = 50;

    Random r = new Random();
    // Keep track of the buttons as we add them to the canvas
    List<ButtonPosition> buttonPositions = new List<ButtonPosition>();

    for (int i = 0; i < numButtons; i++) {
        Button button = new Button();
        button.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right;
        button.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
        button.Margin = new Thickness(3);
        button.Width = buttonWidth;
        button.Height = buttonHeight;
        button.Content = i.ToString();
        bool foundOverlap = false;
        int left;
        int top;
        ButtonPosition bp;  
        do {
            foundOverlap = false;
            // Create a new random position for the button (subtracting the width/height from the X,Y so that we don't overlap the edge of the canvas)
            left = r.Next(0, (int)MyCanvas.ActualWidth - buttonWidth);
            top = r.Next(0, (int)MyCanvas.ActualHeight - buttonHeight);
            bp = new ButtonPosition(left, top, buttonWidth, buttonHeight);
            // Check each of the existing buttons for overlap
            foreach (ButtonPosition existingButton in buttonPositions) {
                if (bp.Overlaps(existingButton)) {
                    foundOverlap = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        } while (foundOverlap);

        // Add the verified button to the canvas
        MyCanvas.Children.Add(button);
        Canvas.SetLeft(button, left);
        Canvas.SetTop(button, top);
        // Add the position of the button to our collection
        buttonPositions.Add(bp);
    }
}
```

This is by no means a perfect solution, as the while loop will be inefficient. It could come up with many overlapping buttons before finding one that doesn't. This will obviously get worse if you add more buttons to the canvas. Also, if you try to add more buttons than will fit, you will get stuck in an infinite loop whilst it looks for space for the button!

Comment: This is definitely one of the finest solutions I received. I was looking for something like this, however no of buttons = 20 is too much, I don't require that much, my requirement will fall between 6 -15. I tested this in my applications and its perfectly working. thanks

Comment: your solution works perfectly if I do a `WPF` project, buttons height, width set perfectly, but if I start a `Windows Phone 8.1` project, it doesn't work as perfectly as it does with `WPF`, in `WP 8.1` there is a overlapping of the buttons. I started changing the height and width of the `buttons` but it doesn't help, all the time buttons height and width are same, as if its not changeable, any idea?

Comment: Even I checked with a button style in `WP8.1`, it does not work, `button.Style = Resources["buttonStyle"] as Style;` where in this tyle I set Height and width as 50, but its not working as it should be

Comment: In WP8.1 I replaced the Button with Rectangle and it works fine there is no overlapping of the rectangles, any idea why only with buttons it does not work? For my code to work I should be working with Buttons only

Comment: Windows Phone 8.1 includes margins on buttons by default, which unfortunately aren't easy to get rid of. Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24725005/size-of-button-in-windows-phone-8-1-app-is-not-expected

Comment: OK, Gary, thanks, I will look into this and surely update this post if anything positive comes out. Thanks

Comment: That `ControlTemplate` resolves the height width issue issue, and I have achieved what I wanted to, but there are many resources compiler response is `could not be resolved`, like example `"The resource "ControlMouseOverColor" could not be resolved."`

Comment: any idea how can I achieve this in MVVM, `canvas_loaded` method If I want to replace with some binding, how can I acieve this, any help.

Comment: Not my area of expertise I'm afraid, I think this would be best posted as a new question.